# How could I avoid writing the similar formula for each cells in one specific column in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How could I - instead of repetition of writing one similar formula for each cells in one column, write one sum function once, that sums all cells subsequently in that specific column?
For example: supposing that I initiate the number of my first A1 cell with 1000, so A2 supposed to be 1001, A3 1003, etc.
I also need to give a boundary like 50 cells in that A column.

Comment: Part of the answer might be as simple as  A1 fill with 1000? A2 formular =A1+1, then copy that formula ? If not, please show us an example of what you want like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb1qa.png (A picture is worth a thousand words).

Comment: You're right @Hennes! It could be simple if I want to copy and paste formula in each cell, but imagine we have at least 12 digits numbers for all at least 100 columns, if we want to initiate each column with a specific number and then copy formula in each cells bellow that current column, it would be so rough and time-consuming. in addition for example for each cell I have to change that A1 index to A2, A3, etc. in order to have  subsequent numbers for other cells. like here: A2= A1 +1 , A3=A2+1, A4= A3+1.

Comment: If you fill down and use relative addressing, the formula will change as you describe in your comment.  If that is not what you want, please explain more clearly.

Comment: I only wrote one formula. And I then cut and pasted it.

Selected cell A2 (which displayed '=A1+1', meaning cell above it plus one), copy. Selected the 48 cells below it. Paste. Done. No need to manually edit formulas.  Works on at least open office, libre office and excel 2016, and probably on every spreadsheet. And after that you could just select cell A1 till A50 (e..g control home. SHIFT control pagedown. copy. (now all 50 cell in copy buffer). Click on B1. Paste. There, another 50 done.  Or even paste directly to the next 99 colums by selecting B till DU and then paste)

Comment: @Hannes , I already knew the formula, it's just a simple loop in programming, but here in Excel 2016, I just don't know how to use the tools.  I didn't understand what you said exactly. could you please edit your typography because of those dots and capital letters? And when I don't manually change the formula, for A3 also the same number would be calculated. something must be wrong.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, What you mean by _Relative addressing_? I just want to make a _do while_ loop using excel formulas that would PLUS one each cell in that column vertically; So,  I would initiate the first cell and then it would be increased with 1 up to n number. It's really simple, but I just need to use Microsoft Excel 2016.

Comment: Excel worksheet formulas do not create *do while* loops.  For help on addressing, check Help for *Switch between relative, absolute, and mixed references* and how they behave as you fill formulas across multiple cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to write a program using C++ to do summation from/to a specific number and it is easy and since I tried to use /t to tab information in order to save the data in a text file and then import it in my desired different columns in Excel.
 
But after that, I found that writing this progression is also possible just with Excel! It's very straightforward! All I needed to was to initiate first and second rows with numbers which create my desired progression for first two rows, and then, just select them and drag them up to a desired number like 50 in my example!!